# Negroni: passing context from middleware to handlers

Tags: go, negroni

I'm trying to add a Gorilla Session to the **Request Context** in a **Negroni** middleware handler so that I can access it in my Gorilla Mux handlers. Here's a stripped down version of my code:

```
// Session Middleware function
func sessMid(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, next 
http.HandlerFunc) {
  ctx := r.Context()
  s, _ := store.Get(r, "user") // store is a CookieStore
  ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, "example", s)

  if !loggedIn() {
    http.Redirect(w, r, "/login", http.StatusFound)
  }

  next(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
}

// Page handler
func pgHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  ctx := r.Context()
  s, ok := ctx.Value("example").(*sessions.Session)
  // ok returns false here, meaning that the session was not returned successfully.
}
```

Hopefully that makes sense. Can anyone point me to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: have you checked if `store.Get` is returning `*sessions.Session`?

Comment: Thanks @jmaloney, your comment helped me find the answer, I was quite stuck.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Redirect statement is receiving the original request without the new context that contains the session. The `WithContext(ctx)` function needs to be used here as well:

```
// Session Middleware function
func sessMid(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, next 
http.HandlerFunc) {
  ctx := r.Context()
  s, _ := store.Get(r, "user") // store is a CookieStore
  ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, "example", s)

  if !loggedIn() {
    // Make sure to add the context to the request sent in the Redirect
    http.Redirect(w, r.WithContext(ctx), "/login", http.StatusFound)
  }

  next(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
}
```

Thanks to [@jmaloney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1817176/jmaloney) for sending me down the right path.

Comment: Works, but using string keys are not recommended for `WithValue`.  Per documentation:  https://godoc.org/net/http#Request.WithContext

Comment: *The provided key must be comparable and should not be of type string or any other built-in type to avoid collisions between packages using context. Users of WithValue should define their own types for keys. To avoid allocating when assigning to an interface{}, context keys often have concrete type struct{}. Alternatively, exported context key variables' static type should be a pointer or interface.)*